# SpringBoot - Error parsing HTTP request header (Oauth2 https endpoints)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

when I am trying to access OAuth HTTPS endpoints from spring boot app , i am getting below error, but HTTP endpoint works perfectly fine

**Error:**

> 2018-07-24 10:25:06.292 [DEBUG][8464][https-jsse-nio-8084-exec-8] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor: Error parsing HTTP request header
>
> java.io.EOFException: null     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1190)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**Endpoints**

```
https://localhost:8084/my-auth/oauth/authorize 
https://localhost:8084/my-auth/oauth/token
```

**Application YML config for ssl:**

```
 port: 8084
    non-http-port: 8083
    context-path: /my-auth
    ssl:
      key-alias: <my cert alais>
      key-password: <my pasword>
      key-store: <my jks path>
      key-store-type: JKS
      enabled: true
```

**Security java Config**

```
  @Bean
   public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern(contextPath+"/api/v1/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };

        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }
    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(unSecuredPort);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(securedPort);
        return connector;
    }
```

**POM file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>my-app-name</artifactId>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <version>my-version</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>my-app-name</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Just, posted on the question, Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, using DB with OAuth2 with Spring Boot 2. `[DEBUG][10168][https-jsse-nio-8483-exec-4] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase: Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5679dbde:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@7522ebbe:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8483 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61610]], Read from buffer: [0]
2018-07-24 11:38:26.178 [DEBUG][10168][https-jsse-nio-8483-exec-4] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor: Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @bavlin

To work Oauth2 endpoints in local you have install certs in local JRE  truststore

Use below command to add that in local trust store: (in command prompt)

•   keytool -keystore cacerts -import -trustcacerts -file "file path to cert"

•   To make it work in postman - In chrome browser , Install localhost cert to “Trusted Root Certification Authorities”

Answer (score 16):

It's not an error, it's a debug message.

I hit this too, and I believe the correct answer is here:

> If the log level were not DEBUG, the EOF would have been silently swallowed.  It's unfortunate that the message says "Unexpected EOF" since in this case it's normal.

which I found on the [tomcat nabble site](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Question-on-Http11AprProcessor-Error-parsing-HTTP-request-header-error-messages-td5031194.html)

The debug message here:

```
   catch (IOException e) {
       if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
           log.debug(sm.getString("http11processor.header.parse"), e);
       }
       setErrorState(ErrorState.CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW, e);
       break;
    }
```

in [Http11Processor from Tomcat 8.5](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.x/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11Processor.java)

And the EOFException which leads to it was added for this Tomcat fix: [Non-blocking should throw an EOFException on EOF as well](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/91b78590169c0a6fa3dfc5a7d0818a5c1c630f44)

which I found from another discussion of this "problem" in this [spring-cloud github discussion](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1306)

> I think this is perfectly normal as this `OEFException` was added by our colleague per [apache/tomcat@91b7859](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/91b78590169c0a6fa3dfc5a7d0818a5c1c630f44). Logging error on INFO level when ssl connection is made to non-ssl connector is a bit aggressive.

Comment: I can verify that when I changed my log level to INFO, the error message went away. Thank you!

Comment: Very thorough and clear answer. Thank you for the links as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution and the problem was with the self signed certificates for the localhost. Once you import these in your truststore for the JDK, everything should work fine.