# nested serializer showing null data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

nested serializer showing null data

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import PlayerTable, ChildTable

class ChildTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # x= ChildTable.objects.all().values
    class Meta:
        model = ChildTable
        fields = ('season','goals','fk')
        # fields =('fk',)

class PlayerTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player_details = ChildTableSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PlayerTable
        fields =  ('player_details',)
```

please help data getting by serializer is null

Comment: class ChildTable(models.Model):
    season = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    goals = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fk = models.ForeignKey('PlayerTable', models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'child_table'

class PlayerTable(models.Model):
    player_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    player_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'player_table'

Comment: Please add more details in your question. What is being null / which line it shows the null and also update the question with errors you are getting.

Comment: And post the relevant code into the question please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823567/eofexception-calling-a-rest-authentication-controller Take this as an example. See how this is formatted with full details.

Comment: @SaurabhGahlot show your model of PlayerTable, ChildTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the field `'player-details'`? It's not a field on your `PlayerTable` model. You need to use the name of the related field. In your case since you have a `ForeignKey` relationship `ChildTable` `-->` `PlayerTable` and you haven't specified the `related_name`, it's `childtable_set`. So if you do this it should work:

```
class PlayerTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    childtable_set = ChildTableSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PlayerTable
        fields =  ('childtable_set',)
```

Alternatively, change your models naming to be more aligned with Django conventions:

```py
class PlayerDetail(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, db_column="fk", related_name="player_details", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "child_table"


class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column="player_name", ...)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "player_table"
```

then your serializer would work because the relation is `player_details`. This also has the advantage that when you do `details.player` you get the player object (now, you have to do `details.fk` but that actually doesn't return the foreign key value, it returns the `Player` object). Also your models have more pythonic names (`Player` not `PlayerTable`). Your code will be much more readable.

Comment: please add reference links (like why use `childtable_set` if there is no related field) to make this answer more complete.