# java.io.EOFException: null

Tags: java

I have encountered the following problem while using Spring boot:
My version of Spring boot is 2.4.0 and JDK version is 1.8.
The interface code for the Controller is as follows:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public Object hello(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
        name+="ok!";
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

I sent a curl request to the server through the terminal with the following request code:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/hello?name=world"
```

At this point the following exception appears in my log:

```
2023-12-28 21:39:20.690 DEBUG 95860 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position() [0]
2023-12-28 21:39:20.690 DEBUG 95860 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4adb5b2d:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7d089058:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:62826]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-12-28 21:39:22.985 DEBUG 95860 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:795) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Combined with some approaches from other developers, I thought long and hard and made the following attempt:

- Modify my curl request to tell me the Context-Length in the request header.
- Send the request with "Transfer-Encoding=chunked" in the request header.
- Set the parameter server.ssl.enable=false in application.properties.

However, none of the above methods solved the problem, so I would like to talk to you in detail about the cause of this exception and effective ideas to solve it.

Comment: That statement is a debug statement, not an error, have you looked at this post? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501360/springboot-error-parsing-http-request-header-oauth2-https-endpoints

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve? Because `name+="ok!"`  doesn't do anything.

Comment: Spring-Boot 2.4.0 is more than 3 years old and Java 8 is almost a decade old. Is this an existing environment you tried to add your controller endpoint to? Or is this a new project you created for learning purposes? If it is the latter I would highly recommend you to start over with Java 21 and Spring-Boot 3.2.1.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I did miss this post. this exception is indeed not an error, just an exception I observed during the process of launching the application. Out of curiosity, I'm trying to figure out why this exception occurs and if there is a workable solution.

Comment: @ValerijDobler Actually this interface is a simplified version used for testing, and this exception appeared after the logging level was upgraded to debug level, trying to figure out some of the reasons why this exception appeared.

Comment: You are missing a RequestMethod at your controller endpoint.

Comment: @ValerijDobler I tried the annotation above the interface changed to @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST) still have the same problem!

Comment: Which import did you used for PathParam?

Comment: @ValerijDobler My import is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this exception per se. The solution would be not to log low level library code on debug.

Answer (score 0):

## EOFException Exception Description

### Exception details

oracle's [explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) of the exception:

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.
> This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream. Note that many other input
> operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.

This exception signals the unexpected arrival of a file endpoint or data stream endpoint during input.

### Problems reappear

#### Controller Code

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public Object hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

#### EOFException reappears

**browser access**

Direct browser access to `http://localhost:8080/hello?name=jjj`

[image: 17038402874698c9a805111934e3c9095684aeaab21c3.png]
**curl request access**

curl request code: `curl -H "Connection: keep-alive" -X POST http://172.21.32.45:8080/hello?name=jjj`

[image: 1703840084776611c4fab19184c049ebbd7c31a1efb7c.png]

**postman access**

The postman request method is:

[image: 1703840329294e032659a70eb461e8c62729fa23a1147.png]

[image: 17038403462618ab5374bb54f4a59bb66547722c878dd.png]
Under the three access methods, the request ends normally and returns the corresponding parameters, only in the curl request access process there is an EOF exception, there is no difference between the three accesses, check the exception information.

```bash
2023-12-29 15:27:19.668 DEBUG 5384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.r.connector.http11.Http11Processor     : Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1296) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
2023-12-29 15:27:19.668 DEBUG 5384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.r.connector.http11.Http11Processor     : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1296) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

In the exception message you can see `CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW` appears, that is, the current connection is closed, and the traffic packets are grabbed by the packet grabber tool in the curl method.

[image: 17038423177625d9db84d238b4154895f23851942d1a0.png]

You can see that during the traffic packet transmission, the data has been transmitted normally, i.e., **this exception does not affect normal HTTP requests**.

### Cause of the problem

When the HTTP request sent by the client is a short connection, the server sends a 200 message to the client after receiving the data, and then the client takes the initiative to start waving. After the hand wave is completed the socket is closed, then at this time because the socket is closed, at this time ** request data has been processed **, but has not jumped out of the cycle of processing the request, so an exception is thrown `Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request`. When a client sends an HTTP request for a long connection, it will only start waving when the connection times out.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

### Impact Statement

The code that throws the exception is as follows:

```java
...
n = getSocket().read(buffer);
if (n == -1) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }
...
```

The reason for the exception is that the server is reading data from the current socket and has reached the end of the data stream (the read method returns -1 when it reaches the end). This part of the code is to prevent non-blocking IO requests from falling into a dead loop leading to OOM, but in fact, before the exception is thrown, the requested data has already been processed, so it will not have an impact on the requested data.